# How to hide title "City" when click on that div in php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to hide the title, "City", when someone clicks on a div. For ex. if a click on Victoria div, then title, "City", is hidden for that div only, other divs remain unaffected. If you click on Toronto div, its title "City" is hidden and title of Victoria div is shown. It's similar to my previous question, "How to use same onclick function multiple times in php page?", but it won't work here. Any solution with javascript, Jquery?

[image]

Php Code :

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
// Check connection
if($link === false)
{
 die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Attempt select query execution
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM sample";
   if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
            echo "<div style='border: 2px solid black;'><p class='CityTitle".$row['id']."'>City</p>". $row['UserCity'] ."</p></div></br>";
    }
    // Close result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  } 
   else
  {
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  }
 } 
  else
 {
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }
  // Close connection
  mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

Comment: give a unique id to each div using `$row['(id) or ('usercity')']` and to the label for city, then handle onclick in js accordingly

Comment: [jQuery .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) will do what you need, for more specific help you might want to post some JavaScript code :)

Comment: @AlexG I am not apply any javascript code now because don't know how to apply ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit I update my code can it helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want following behavior:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cityContainer > div").click(function() {
    $(".cityContainer").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active .CityTitle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cityContainer">

  <div style='border: 2px solid black;'>
    <p class='CityTitle'>City</p>Victoria</div>
  </br>

  <div style='border: 2px solid black;'>
    <p class='CityTitle'>City</p>Toronto</div>
  </br>

 <div style='border: 2px solid black;'>
    <p class='CityTitle'>City</p>Ottawa</div>
  </br>

</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain inside "cityContainer > div" why > sign is used.

Comment: in jquery `>` means immediate child. So ".cityContainer > div" means all the `div` which are immediate children of div with class `cityContainer`. Hope this is clear to you. Please have look ta doc at https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I think below solution may be helpfull to you , create a click event of the div , and find the class 'CityTitle' which you right in you code and hide using the class. Try this code:

```
$('document').on('click','div',function(){
    $(this).find('.CityTitle').hide();
})
```

I hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.cityName').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.cityHeading').hide();
})
```

```css
.cityBorder{border:1px solid #000; padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px}
.cityHeading{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cityBorder"><div class="cityHeading">City</div><div class="cityName">Ottawa</div></div>
<div class="cityBorder"><div class="cityHeading">City</div><div class="cityName">victoria</div></div>
<div class="cityBorder"><div class="cityHeading">City</div><div class="cityName">st.john's</div></div>
<div class="cityBorder"><div class="cityHeading">City</div><div class="cityName">Totonto</div></div>
<div class="cityBorder"><div class="cityHeading">City</div><div class="cityName">quebee city</div></div>
```

Hope this makes you happy

Comment: its look slightly different. but, I got answer.